# С4 информатика: как запомнить имя участника?

Tags: c

На городской олимпиаде по информатике участникам было предложено выполнить 3 задания, каждое из которых оценивалось по 25-балльной шкале. Известно, что общее количество участников первого тура олимпиады не превосходит 250 человек. На вход программы подаются сведения о результатах олимпиады. В первой строке вводится количество участников N. Далее следуют N строк, имеющих следующий формат:

<Фамилия> <Имя> <Баллы>

Здесь <Фамилия> – строка, состоящая не более чем из 20 символов; <Имя> – строка, состоящая не более чем из 15 символов; <Баллы> – строка, содержащая три целых числа, разделенных пробелом, соответствующих баллам, полученным участником за каждое задание первого тура. При этом <Фамилия> и <Имя>, <Имя> и <Баллы> разделены одним пробелом. Примеры входных строк:

Петрова Ольга 25 18 16

Калиниченко Иван 14 19 15

Напишите программу, которая будет выводить на экран фамилию и имя участника, набравшего максимальное количество баллов. Если среди остальных участников есть ученики, набравшие такое же количество баллов, то их фамилии и имена также следует вывести. При этом имена и фамилии можно выводить в произвольном порядке.

Вот то,что я придумал:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
    int dig[100];/*счетчик*/
    char fam[19];
    char name[14];
    int i,j,n,c,st,rez1,rez2,rez3,rezmax,rez;

    printf("Кол-воо участников :\n");
    scanf("%d",n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        dig[i] = 0;/*Все элементы счетчика равны нулю*/
    }
    printf("\nВводите результаты:\n");
    rezmax = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        scanf("%s %s %d %d %d",&fam,&name,&rez1,&rez2,&rez3);
        rez = rez1 + rez2 + rez3;
        dig[i] = rez;
        if(rez > rezmax){
            rezmax = rez;
        }
    }

}
```

Начал разбираться,пишу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
    struct Rez {
        char fam[20];
        char name[15];
        int rez;    
    } ;
    int rez1;
    int rez2;
    int rez3;
    struct Rez dig[100];
    int i,j,n,tmp;

    printf("Введите число участников: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Введите имена и результаты участников: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ ){
        scanf("%s %s %d %d %d",&Rez.fam,&Rez.name,&rez1,&rez3,&rez3);
        Rez.rez = rez1 + rez2 + rez3;
            dig[i] = Rez;
    }

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i-- ){ 
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++ ){
            if (dig[i].rez > dig[j].rez){
                tmp = dig[j];
                dig[i] = dig[j];
                dig[j] = tmp;
            }   
        }   
    }

    printf("\n%s %s %d",dig[n - 1].fam,dig[n - 1].name,dig[n - 1].rez);
    return 0;
}
```

А мне в ответ:

```
ошибка: unknown type name «Rez»
```

со всеми вытекающими. Повторюсь, опыта общения с текстурами у меня около часа. Где я наошибался? Спасибо.

Подправил,теперь:

```
c2.c:22:29: ошибка: «Rez» undeclared (first use in this function)
c2.c:22:29: замечание: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
c2.c:30:13: ошибка: incompatible types when assigning to type «int» from type «struct Rez»
c2.c:32:16: ошибка: incompatible types when assigning to type «struct Rez» from type «int»
```

Где я ошибся?

Проблемы решены [Сортировка массива структур.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222743/c-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80) ,тему можно закрыть.

Comment: Создайте структурку для хранения данных участника. Строки копируйте с помощью strcpy. Поместите все такие структурки в один массив, отсортируйте по убыванию баллов.

это как? без структур желательно

Comment: А почему вы именно С выбрали для сдачи ЕГЭ? Насколько я знаю задачки ЕГЭ можно решать практически на любом языке. А вот вероятность зафейлить на С очень большая.

Comment: Не, если конечно вам так не по душе использование структур, то можете создать несколько параллельных массивов, которые будут хранить все данные, которые могли бы удобно уместиться в полях структуры. О рациональности и логике такого способа уже судите сами.

Comment: @0xFFh, тогда уж, заодно, посоветовали бы ТС переключиться на фортран.

Answer (score 3):

[@rolton](/users/12150/rolton), без структур будут серьезные проблемы с несколькими участниками, набравшими максимальный балл.

А считывать все и сортировать - это "неспортивно". Задача решается за один проход по файлу, в памяти накапливаются только "максималисты".

Только для этого Вам придется ознакомиться с такой темой, как списки.
(впрочем проблемы здесь нет, по ним вопросов на ХК было немеряно).

Comment: А если посмотреть вышенаписанное,где я не прав и как лучше быть?

Comment: Действительно, в условии задачи сказано, что в первой строке указано N - количество участников.

Но Вы ведь участвуете в *олимпиаде*, вот и прыгните выше, чем поставленная планка. Решите задачу для **произвольного** числа участников.

Все, что Вам для этого нужно, это уметь определить конец файла (т.е. данных больше нет) и знакомство с динамическим выделением памяти (см. `man malloc`), а следовательно с *указателями*.

--

По поводу ошибок:

имя Rez нигде не объявлено. Видимо нужно struct Rez { ... } Rez;

tmp д.б. иметь тип struct Rez, а не int.

В scanf перед Rez... & не нужно.

и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте структурку для хранения данных участника. Строки копируйте с помощью strcpy. Поместите все такие структурки в один массив, отсортируйте по убыванию баллов. Выведите имена и фамилии всех участников имеющих столько же быллов сколько у первого (включая первого). PROFIT!

У вас кстати недостаточно элементов в fam и name -- должно быть 20 + 1 и 15 + 1 соответственно.