# Сортировка массива структур.

Tags: c

Из списка участников,выбрать того,у которого самая высокая сумма баллов.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>

    main(){
        struct Rezultat {
            char fam[20];
            char name[15];
            int rez;    
        } Rez;
        int rez1;
        int rez2;
        int rez3;
        struct Rezultat dig[100];
        int i,j,n;
        struct Rezultat tmp;

        printf("Введите число участников: \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("Введите имена и результаты участников: \n");

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
            scanf("%s %s %d %d %d",Rez.fam,Rez.name,&rez1,&rez3,&rez3);
            Rez.rez = rez1 + rez2 + rez3;
            dig[i] = Rez;
        Rez.rez = 0;
        }

        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){ 
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++ ){
                if (dig[j].rez > dig[i].rez){
                    tmp = dig[j];
                    dig[i] = dig[j];
                    dig[j] = tmp;
                }   
            }   
        }

        printf("\n%s %s %d",dig[n - 1].fam,dig[n - 1].name,dig[n - 1].rez);
        return 0;
    }
```

c2.c:24:21: предупреждение: «rez2» may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
Что это может значить?ЗЫ:выводитс биллиберда,почему?Заранее спасибо.

Переделал,возможно не рационально,но если учесть что со строками я знаком два дня,а с структурами 3 часа,то мне кажется я справился:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
    struct Rezultat {
        char fam[20];
        char name[15];
        int rez;    
    } Rez;
    int rez1;
    int rez2;
    int rez3;
    struct Rezultat dig[100];
    int i,j,n,mm;
    struct Rezultat tmp;

    printf("Введите число участников: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Введите имена и результаты участников: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        scanf("%s %s %d %d %d",Rez.fam,Rez.name,&rez1,&rez2,&rez3);
        Rez.rez = rez1 + rez2 + rez3;
        dig[i] = Rez;
    }

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i-- ){ 
        mm = 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++ ){
            if (dig[j].rez > dig[i].rez){
                mm = j;
                tmp = dig[i];
                dig[i] = dig[mm];
                dig[mm] = tmp;
            }   
        }   
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1 ; i++){
        if(dig[n - 1].rez == dig[i].rez ){
            printf("\n%s %s\n",dig[i].fam,dig[i].name); 
        }
    }

    printf("\n%s %s\n",dig[n - 1].fam,dig[n - 1].name);
    return 0;
}
```

Самое рациональное,на что я способен:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
    struct Rezultat {
        char fam[20];
        char name[15];
        int rez;    
    } Rez;
    int rez1;
    int rez2;
    int rez3,rezmax;
    struct Rezultat dig[100];
    int i,n;

    printf("Введите число участников: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Введите имена и результаты участников: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        scanf("%s %s %d %d %d",Rez.fam,Rez.name,&rez1,&rez2,&rez3);
        Rez.rez = rez1 + rez2 + rez3;
        dig[i] = Rez;
    }
    rezmax = 0;
    /*поиск максимального результата*/
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        if(dig[i].rez > rezmax){
            rezmax = dig[i].rez;
        }
    }
    /*Поиск результатов,схожих с максимальным*/
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        if(rezmax == dig[i].rez){
            printf("\n%s %s",dig[i].fam,dig[i].name);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо,avp,0xFFh!

Comment: Опечатка в строке 23

Comment: У Вас опечатка в scanf(). Вместо &rez1, &rez2, &rez3 два раза пишете &rez3.

Comment: @rolton, а зачем Вам сортировка, если в описанной Вами задаче (насколько помню) требуются участники (или только один участник) с **максимальным** баллом?

IMHO достаточно найти максимум и запомнить остальных, равных этому максимуму.

--

По поводу хранения в памяти всех данных. Дело, конечно, Ваше, но по моему это некрасиво. Надо бы накапливать только те данные, которые нужны и допустить, что количество участников может быть любым, не известным при запуске программы. 

Они же берутся из файла. Вот по концу файла Вы и завершите свою обработку.

Это будет правильно.

Comment: У вас по прежнему не хватает места в массивах fam и name!  В C строкихраняться с нулевым символом в конце, поэтому памяти надо на один символ больше, чем длина строки. Это очень важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если это вся задача:**

```
Из списка участников,выбрать того,у которого самая высокая сумма баллов.
```

то в чем же у вас проблема? Если все участники( соответственно, экземпляры структуры ) находятся в массиве, то можно просто пробежаться по всем структурам в массиве с помощью обычного цикла, сравнивая при этом поля "reZ"( количество баллов, как понимаю ).

Это один из самых примитивных алгоритмов - алгоритм поиска в массиве минимального значения.

Comment: Если несколько человек набрали максимальные результаты,то нужно вывести их всех.Ничего рациональнее ,чем сортировать и выводить максимальные,мне не пришло.За совет спасибо.

Comment: @rolton, даже если остановиться на массиве структур в памяти, то сортировать его **явно не рационально**.

--

Первым проходом ищете максимум. Вторым печатаете всех, равных максимуму. 

Вот и все.

Comment: Да ну пока разбирался со структурами,пока один учебник полистал,пока другой,пока здесь вопрос закрыли,всё нормальное из головы вылетело.

Comment: @rolton, вам правильно говорит @avp : сортировать массив лишь для поиска в нем минимума/максимума НЕ РАЦИОНАЛЬНО. Тем более, в вашем случае сортировка( любым алгоритмом ), вероятнее, "съест" на порядок больше ресурсов, чем обычный пробег по массиву.

Comment: поправил код,теперь лучше

Comment: @rolton, только что пришло в голову, код можно еще оптимизировать. 

Ищите максимум в том же цикле, где вводите структуры. Просто перенесите `rezmax = 0;` перед циклом ввода, а в его конец вставьте `if (dig[i].rez > rezmax) ...`